# Method Needs to return a value from a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

I need to create a method for my Television class that will receive an integer, but will return a string value (channel name) from an array. I am having trouble in the toString() are where I am receiving an error "error- '.class' expected' for the part that is supposed to display the channel name. Thanks and here is my code.

```
public class Television
```

{

```
private int channel;
private int currentChannel;
private int volume;
private boolean power;
private String[] channelName = {"CBS", "FOX", "DISCOVERY", "PBS", "HBO", "CNN", "DISNEY", "CNN", "TBS", "USA"};



//No argument constructor
public Television()
{
    currentChannel = 1;
    volume = 0;
    power = false;

}


public void powerChange()
{
    this.power = !this.power;
}

public void setVolume(int vol)
{
    if (vol>10)
    {
    volume = 10;
    }else
    {
        volume = vol;
    }
    if (vol<0)
    {
    volume = 0;
    }

}

public void increaseVolume()
{
    volume++;
}

public void decreaseVolume()
{
    volume--;
}

public int getVolume()
{
    return volume;
}

public void setChannel(int ch)
{
    if(ch>10)
    {
    channel = 10;
    }else
    {
        channel = ch;
    }
    if(ch<1)
    {
    channel = 1;
    }
}

public void increaseChannel()
{
    channel++;
}

public void decreaseChannel()
{
    channel--;
}

public int getChannel()
{
    return channel;
}

public String getChannelName(int channel)
{

    if (channel==1)
    {
        return channelName[0];
    }
    else if (channel == 2)
    {
        return channelName[1];
    }   
    else if (channel == 3)
    {
        return channelName[2];
    }   
    else if (channel == 4)
    {
        return channelName[3];
    }   
    else if (channel == 5)
    {
        return channelName[4];
    }   
    else if (channel == 6)
    {
        return channelName[5];
    }   
    else if (channel == 7)
    {
        return channelName[6];
    }
    else if (channel == 8)
    {
        return channelName[7];
    }   
    else if (channel == 9)
    {
        return channelName[8];
    }   
    else if (channel == 10)
    {
        return channelName[9];
    }   


}


public String toString()
{
    if(!power)
    {
        return String.format("%s :%s\n%s :%d\n %s :%s\n%s :%d", "TV State", "OFF", "Channel No", channel, "Channel Name", getChannelName(channel), "Volume", volume);
    }
    else if(power)
    {
        return String.format("%s :%s\n%s :%d\n %s :%s\n%s :%d", "TV State", "ON", "Channel No", channel, "Channel Name", getChannelName(channel), "Volume", volume);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: What do you think this piece of code does: `getchannelName[]`?

Comment: I did not have getchannelName[] in my original code, but I was trying to play with the toString() just to see if anything would help it. I was trying to invoke the method I had created earlier but I realize that this did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TVChannel[] channelName = {"CBS", "FOX", "DISCOVERY", "PBS", "HBO", 
                           "CNN", "DISNEY", "CNN", "TBS", "USA"};
```

Should be

```
String[] channelName = {"CBS", "FOX", "DISCOVERY", "PBS", "HBO", 
                        "CNN", "DISNEY", "CNN", "TBS", "USA"};
```

Your array is of `TVChannel type` and should be of `String` type.  `TVChannel` is a class that does not even exist.

**Edit: also consider**

```
channelName = new TVChannel[MaxChannel];  // delete this from your constructor.
                                          // it is not needed. Your instance of
                                          // the class already give you array
```

Also consider your `getChannelName()` method. Maybe you swant take an `int` argument?

```
public String getChannelName(int channel){ // instead of using the instance var
                                           // the logic really doesn't make sense
                                           // for your situation

}
```

Comment: Or it needs to list instances of `TVChannel`, which ever the OP actually needs ;)

Comment: Thanks. I have changed this but I am still receiving the same error message.

Comment: @user2981579, you don't need this piece of code in your constructor `channelName = new TVChannel[MaxChannel];`

Comment: @peeskillet thank you, that does make more sense. Any tips on how to refer to it in the toString method? I am still getting and error from this.

Comment: @user2981579 `getchannelName[]`. You want `getChannel(channel)` in your `toString()`. What error are you getting? Is it just in the `toString()`?

Comment: @peeskillet I changed **getchannelName[]** to **getChannelName(channel)** and am receiving the error "Cannot find the symbol getChannelName(channel).

Comment: @user2981579, notice the case difference. Look at the method in your class. Java is case-sensitive

Comment: Yes that did help, but now it is giving me an error that I am missing return statements after the toString and getChanngelName(channel). I will update what my code looks like above. @peeskillet

Comment: @user2981579, romove the `if(power)` from `else if(power)`. You don't need that. You just need `else`. And put `return null` at the very bottom of your `getChannelName()` method. That should take care of those two errors.

Comment: Code finally compiled. Thank you so much @peeskillet! You helped me in my process of learning java!